# Incorrect results while cropping with gdalwarp and cutlineSQL

Tags: python, gdal, clip, gdalwarp

**Environment:** Windows 10, Python 3.7, Numpy 1.18 and GDAL 3.0.2

[image]

**Data required:**

1. Single band raster
2. Polygons on same area with an attribute "name"

[image]

The code below works fine and cuts the data for all 3 polygons

```
ds = gdal.Warp('cut.tif', 'ndvi.tif', format = 'GTiff', cutlineDSName = 'parcel.shp')

if ds is None:
    print('Failed')
else:
    print('Success')
# prints Success
```

[image]

But this does not work

```
ds = gdal.Warp('first-wrong.tif', 'ndvi.tif', format = 'GTiff', \
               cutlineDSName = 'parcel.shp', \
               cutlineSQL = 'SELECT * FROM parcel', \
               cutlineWhere = 'name = "first"')

if ds is None:
    print('Failed')
else:
    print('Success')
# prints Success but gives same result as previous
```

Expected output:
[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: In case you wish to reproduce it with my data, it is here (Zipped download <400KB) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1md7Z0CtgYHIWbK96UUm11BMdSM0-ioVs?usp=sharing

Comment: Note your shapefile did not include the parcel.dbf

Comment: Thank you noticing. Fixed that. The missing file does not affect the problem.

Comment: Actually it does, because the code will not work at all without the attribute table (the .dbf file)

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is using double quotes for the string literal.

The [OGR SQL documentation](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#string-literals-and-identifiers-quoting) specifies *single quotes* are required for strings. Double quotes are used for field names (only required if they contain special characters or reserved words):

> **String literals and identifiers quoting**
>
> Strict SQL92 rules are applied regarding string literals and
> identifiers quoting.
>
> String literals (constants) must be surrounded
> with **single-quote characters**. e.g. `WHERE a_field = 'a_value'`
> Identifiers (column names and tables names) can be used unquoted if
> they don’t contain special characters or are not a SQL reserved
> keyword. Otherwise they must be surrounded with double-quote
> characters. e.g. `WHERE "from" = 5`.

This works:

```
ds = gdal.Warp('first-right.tif', 'ndvi.tif', format = 'GTiff',
                cutlineDSName='parcel.shp',
                cutlineWhere='name = \'first\'')
```

Or

```
ds = gdal.Warp('first-right.tif', 'ndvi.tif', format = 'GTiff',
                cutlineDSName='parcel.shp',
                cutlineWhere="name = 'first'")
```

[image]

Comment: OGR SQL dialect documentation is a treasure trove! Thank you for finding the issue.